# how do you set a constraint where the number is 13 character long and must start with zero in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

the question is '13-digit number and may begin with a zero' anyone able to help?

Comment: what have you tried? What type is number? [Check constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) are fairly new.

Comment: "must start with zero" or "may begin with a zero"?

Comment: You can build this kind of business logic into the query itself, but also this sounds like a simple display issue, easily resolved with padding (especially if both the first and second digits can simultaneously be zero)